# How to persist ethtool settings through reboot on debian 8

Tags: debian, linux-networking

Hello how can i persist the following setting through reboot on a debian 8?

```
ethtool -K eth0 lro off
ethtool -K eth1 lro off
```

I already have try to add it under /etc/network/interfaces.d/ifcfg-bond0 with the following option:

```
ETHTOOL_OPTIONS='-K eth0 lro off'
ETHTOOL_OPTIONS='-K eth1 lro off'
```

But this doesn't work. Can somebody help me please?

Comment: Write a custom udev rule to `/etc/udev/rules.d/`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Multiple possibilities come to mind:

- Put the lines into `/etc/network/interfaces` (or whatever file you're using underneath `interfaces.d`:

  ```
  iface eth0 inet static
      [...]
      post-up /sbin/ethtool -K eth0 lro off
      post-up /sbin/ethtool -K eth1 lro off
  ```

  (Actually maybe this is the most appropriate place, because it keeps network settings in one place.)
- Put the lines into `/etc/rc.local`, which is executed during startup, before `exit 0` at the bottom:

  ```
   [...]
   /sbin/ethtool -K eth0 lro off && /sbin/ethtool -K eth1 lro off
   exit 0
  ```
- Put these lines into the `crontab` of a user which is able to run the commands, edit it via `crontab -e`:

  ```
   [...]
   @reboot /sbin/ethtool -K eth0 lro off && /sbin/ethtool -K eth1 lro off
   [...]
  ```

Comment: The first point have worked for me I only change /usr/sbin/ethtool to /sbin/ethtool. Thank you for the solution

Comment: @pluto Thanks for your comment, I've fixed the path. Sorry for the typo.

Answer (score 0):

Add the line

```
offload-lro off
```

to your interface definition in `/etc/network/interfaces`.

See
`/usr/share/doc/ethtool/README.Debian` for more supported ethtool options.